# GraphQL: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, django, graphql, django-graphql-jwt

## Description

I am trying to build an API for a transportation system which has different kind of users (Driver, Customer, SystemAdmin and Authorizer). For this purpose I created an `AbstractUser` and use inheritance relationship for the all of the above different users.
For adding JWT to the model, I have read the [official tutorial](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/), but whenever I want to create a new user like the following I faced to the error:

```
mutation {
  register(
    email: "new_user@email.com",
    username: "new_user",
    password1: "supersecretpassword",
    password2: "supersecretpassword",
  ) {
    success,
    errors,
    token,
    refreshToken
  }
}
```

## Steps to Reproduce

1. Here is my model:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


# Create your models here.
class Usermodel(AbstractUser, models.Model):
    phone_no = models.CharField(
        max_length=11,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="Phone Number"
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"   # e.g: "username", "email"
    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"         # e.g: "email", "primary_email"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    
class Driver(Usermodel, models.Model):
    national_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, 
        blank=True, 
        verbose_name="National ID"
    )

    profile_picture = models.ImageField(
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        ('1', 'Free'),
        ('2', 'Busy')
    ]

    driver_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES
    )

    rating = models.FloatField(
        default=-1
    )

    ranking = models.IntegerField(
        default=-1
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Driver'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Drivers'

class Authorizer(Usermodel, models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Authorizer'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Authorizers'

class Customer(Usermodel, models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Customer'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Customers'

class Administrator(Usermodel, models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Adminsitrator'
        verbose_name_plural='Administrators'
```

2. users schema

```py
import graphene
from graphene import Mutation, ObjectType, InputObjectType
from .models import Driver, Authorizer, Customer, Administrator
from graphene_django.types import DjangoObjectType


class DriverType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Driver

class AuthorizerType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Authorizer

class Query(ObjectType):
    driver = graphene.Field(
        DriverType,
        id = graphene.ID()
    )

    authorizer = graphene.Field(
        AuthorizerType,
        id = graphene.ID()
    )

    all_drivers = graphene.List(DriverType)
    all_authorizers = graphene.List(AuthorizerType)

    def resolve_all_drivers(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Driver.objects.all()

    def resolve_driver(self, info, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs.get('id')
        if id is not None:
            return Driver.objects.get(pk=id)

    def resolve_authorizer(self, info, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs.get('id')
        if id is not None:
            return Driver.objects.get(pk=id)

    def resolve_all_authorizers(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Authorizer.objects.all()


class DriverInput(InputObjectType):
    first_name = graphene.String()
    last_name = graphene.String()
    email = graphene.String()
    username = graphene.String()
    phone_no = graphene.String()
    national_id = graphene.String()
    password = graphene.String()


class AuthorizerInput(InputObjectType):
    first_name = graphene.String()
    last_name = graphene.String()
    email = graphene.String()
    username = graphene.String()
    phone_no = graphene.String()
    password = graphene.String()
class CreateDriver(Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        driver_data = DriverInput()
        
    driver = graphene.Field(DriverType)

    def mutate(self, info, driver_data=None):
        driver = Driver(
            first_name=driver_data.first_name,
            last_name=driver_data.last_name,
            email=driver_data.email,
            username=driver_data.username,
            phone_no=driver_data.phone_no,
            national_id=driver_data.national_id,
            password=driver_data.password
        )

        driver.save()

        return CreateDriver(
            driver=driver
        )

class UpdateDriver(Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.ID()
        driver_data = DriverInput()
    
    driver = graphene.Field(DriverType)

    def mutate(self, info, id, driver_data=None):
        #TODO: Error handling if the id not exists
        driver = Driver.objects.get(pk=id)

        driver.first_name = driver_data.first_name
        driver.last_name = driver_data.last_name
        driver.email = driver_data.email
        driver.username = driver_data.username
        driver.phone_no = driver_data.phone_no
        driver.national_id = driver_data.national_id
        driver.password = driver_data.password
        driver.save()

        return UpdateDriver(driver=driver)


class AuthorizerInput(InputObjectType):
    first_name = graphene.String()
    last_name = graphene.String()
    email = graphene.String()
    username = graphene.String()
    phone_no = graphene.String()
    password = graphene.String()

class CreateAuthorizer(Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        authorizer_data = AuthorizerInput()

    authorizer = graphene.Field(AuthorizerInput)

    def mutate(self, info, authorizer_data=None):
        authorizer = Authorizer(
            firstname=authorizer_data.first_name,
            last_name=authorizer_data.last_name,
            email=authorizer_data.email,
            username=authorizer_data.username,
            phone_no=authorizer_data.phone_no,
            password=authorizer_data.password
        )
        authorizer.save()
        return CreateAuthorizer(authorizer=authorizer)

class UpdateAuthorizer(Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.ID()
        authorizer_data = AuthorizerInput()
    
    authorizer = graphene.Field(AuthorizerType)
    
    def mutate(self, info, id, authorizer_data=None):
        authorizer = Authorizer.objects.get(pk=id)
        authorizer.first_name = authorizer_data.first_name
        authorizer.last_name = authorizer_data.last_name
        authorizer.email = authorizer_data.email
        authorizer.username = authorizer_data.username
        authorizer.password = authorizer_data.password
        authorizer.save()

        return UpdateDriver(authorizer=authorizer)

class Mutations(ObjectType):
    create_driver = CreateDriver.Field()
    update_driver = UpdateDriver.Field()
```

3. project schema

```py
import graphene

from apps.users.schema import Query as user_query
from apps.users.schema import Mutations as user_mutation
from graphql_auth.schema import UserQuery, MeQuery
from graphql_auth import mutations

class AuthMutation(graphene.ObjectType):
   register = mutations.Register.Field()


class Query(user_query, UserQuery, MeQuery):
    pass

class Mutations(user_mutation, AuthMutation):
    pass    

schema = graphene.Schema(
    query=Query,
    mutation=Mutations
)
```

### Expected behavior

I expect the code to run without any problem but face to the following error in `actual behavior`

I also have another question. As I have explained for the various kind of user and registration of them, I need different arguments. But in schema we just add `register = mutations.Register.Field()`, How can I reach to this purpose?

### Actual behavior

[image: error description]

## Requirements

```
aniso8601==7.0.0
asgiref==3.2.10
Django==3.0.8
django-filter==2.3.0
django-graphql-auth==0.3.11
django-graphql-jwt==0.3.0
graphene==2.1.8
graphene-django==2.12.1
graphql-core==2.3.2
graphql-relay==2.0.1
Pillow==7.2.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
promise==2.3
PyJWT==1.7.1
pytz==2020.1
Rx==1.6.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
Unidecode==1.1.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question 1: I expect the code to run without any problem but face to the following error in actual behavior

> N.B. It's going to be a little difficult to answer this without seeing how your `settings.py` is configured, but double-check that you went through every step. I went through the quickstart too but still missed a few spots.

### A: Make sure you have your `settings.py` properly configured

I ran into a similar "Connection refused" error, but the issue was that my settings were not configured properly.

> Edit: After further local development and toggling with individual settings, I realized that my "Connection refused error was related to not having `EMAIL_BACKEND` configured. It was trying to connect to any SMTP server that wasn't running. Make sure you have `EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"` set to log this functionality to your console.

Here's a slightly abbreviated copy of my `settings.py` from a scratch project I was using, just to be sure that you have it configured correctly:

Source: [django-graphql-auth quickstart](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/).

*N.B.: It's a little long, make sure to scroll all the way through*

```
# ...


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    
    # Package apps
    "corsheaders",
    "graphene_django",
    "graphql_jwt.refresh_token.apps.RefreshTokenConfig",
    "graphql_auth",
    "django_filters",

    # Created apps
    "users", # or whatever the name of the app is with your custom users model
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "<project_name>.urls"

# TEMPLATES = ...
# WSGI_APPLICATION = ...
# DATABASES = ...

# Ensure that custom user is set
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.CustomUser"

# AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = ...

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

# ...

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
# ...

GRAPHENE = {
    "SCHEMA": "backend.schema.schema",
    "MIDDLEWARE": ["graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware",],
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "graphql_jwt.backends.JSONWebTokenBackend",
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "graphql_auth.backends.GraphQLAuthBackend",
]

GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    "JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION": True,
    "JWT_LONG_RUNNING_REFRESH_TOKEN": True,
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"
```

### Question 2: As I have explained for the various kind of user and registration of them, I need different arguments. But in schema we just add register = mutations.Register.Field(), How can I reach to this purpose?

### A: TLDR - this is explained in the [dynamic fields](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/#dynamic-fields) section of the settings docs.

### A: Walkthrough

#### Step 1: Make sure that your custom user model has the field set

Before we think about updating our settings, confirm that the custom field you need to set exists on the model. For example, if I wanted to have a `luck_number` field, I would add:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ...

    luck_number = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

Then you need to make sure you run migrations so that this exists in your database.
`python manage.py makemigrations`
`python manage.py migrate`

#### Step 2: Add `GRAPHQL_AUTH` to `settings.py`

In your settings, make sure to set:

```
# Rest of your settings ...

GRAPHQL_AUTH = {}
```

#### Step 3: Add your custom fields and double-check your schema

If you want to add fields to collect on registration, you need to add the `REGISTER_MUTATION_FIELDS` to your `GRAPHQL_AUTH` settings. So in the case of adding `luck_number` to our `register` mutation:

```
GRAPHQL_AUTH = {
  REGISTER_MUTATION_FIELDS = {
    "email": "String",
    "username": "String",
    "luck_number": "Int",
  }
}
```

[image: register mutation with custom field]

**edit 1: adding image**

**edit 2: adding clarification around my error on register mutation**

Comment: Wow! what a complete answer. Thank you Frank. Welcome to the stackoverflow man! :)

Comment: Thanks @MostafaGhadimi, happy hacking :)